# JointController: Does the PID calculate torque to apply to joint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What exactly is does a [gazebo::physics::JointController](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1JointController.html) do to control the joint position/velocity?

I can see from the API documentation that you can set up a PID controller within the JointController, and you can ultimately specify P/I/D gains and min/max control effort.  However, I'm not sure what the "control effort" is that is calculated by the PID controller inside of the JointController.  Is it the force/torque applied to the joint?

On another note, I see no way in the documentation to specify which axis of the joint you want to control using a JointController.  What happens if you are using a revolute2 joint with two axes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13084/jointcontroller:-does-the-pid-calculate-torque-to-apply-to-joint?/) by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 207 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In my experience, the control effort is equal to the force applied. I haven't validated this, but that what I've always assumed it to be. It also seems you're correct about `JointController` only handling one axis. Of course implementing PID is very easy, and you can do it yourself. This means you can call `SetForce(axis, force)` and specify which axis you want to control. The JointController probably defaults to the first axis specified in sdf.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you have a doubt because the documentation isn't precise enough, just check the code directly on Bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/7081a5b47d14fc6f1fa6a191ada381483f92460a/gazebo/physics/JointController.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

For position PIDs, here is how it uses the common::PID class and the SetForce() function:

```
double cmd = this->dataPtr->posPids[iter->first].Update(this->dataPtr->joints[iter->first]->GetAngle(0).Radian() -  iter->second, stepTime);
this->dataPtr->joints[iter->first]->SetForce(0, cmd);
```

---

Originally posted by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) with karma: 198 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1